# Symfony2 Profiler empty result in database panel

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, profiler

I am currently working on a private project that needs a high count on sql queries per page.
Therefor i wanted to fix that by reviewing the requests and trying to optimize.
i am using Symfony2 with Doctrine2 and the Symfony2 profiler.

The problem is, that i get an empty result page by my browser when i try to open the panel=db tab.
In the profiler bar i can see the query count(140, can be higher depending on users entries).
When i open the database panel on a page with a lower count of db queries, the panel works without any remarks.

Has anyone else faced this problem and knows a solution?

Best regards

Freddy

Comment: More than hundred queries on one page? Maybe profiler stuck suggest you to optimize code? I think it's a problem with rendering huge amount of html (or maybe calculating it by SF).

Comment: @KarolWojciechowski thats exactly what i thought too, sadly optimization will be hard, as im running statistical analysis on my db. Just wanted to know if this is a well known error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the profile stores the collected data in files in the cache directory. You could try to change the storage system to a more suitable one for such amount of data.

Here you have information on how to do it-> [Switching the Profiler Storage](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/profiler/storage.html)

Hope it helps.